# Do we need to double margins, widths and heights of container like divs for iPad retina display?

Tags: ipad, retina-display

I really need a guidance on this. I am designing a web app which should support pad retina display. My client has given me style guide in which he doubled everything like margins, heights and widths of elements? Do we need to do that or we just need graphics like images, icons in double size?

Please help me, I am stuck.

Thanks,

Comment: What are you developing on?  If you're on a mac you could just install xcode and use the ipad simulator.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about margins, widths and heights in terms of CSS in your web app, the answer is no, you do not need to double them for the retina display. When you specify a height, width or margin or anything else in your CSS, it will display in the correct size on a normal display and a retina display will do the double pixel conversion internally so it uses double the device pixels. You do not need to do anything to support this in that respect.

Here is an image from [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/) explaining it best:

[image: CSS vs Device Pixels]

For images, you will need to create `@2x` images to have them look retina on the retina iPhone and iPad. Smashing Magazine posted a great article last month called [Towards a Retina Web](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/) which explains this really well and gives tips on various retina image techniques